# The term 'connect-nacontroller' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program

Tags: vb.net, powershell

Doesn't it figure.  Moments after I post this, I finally get it to work.  I'll post what I did just in case anyone else has this issue in the futures.  It's a big oversight for me!

Right before the username line, I added this line:
    "Import-Module DataOnTap" & Environment.NewLine & _**

I'm trying to run a PowerShell script from within VB.Net 2010 code.  When I run the code in PowerShell, it runs fine.  When I run it from within VS2010, I get the error:
"The term 'connect-nacontroller' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again."
The error occurs when it gets to the "Dim results As Collection(Of PSObject) = MyPipeline.Invoke()" line.

Here is my code (I changed the username and password and will be changing how it comes into the code once I get it to work.  I also changed the name of the volume):

```
Protected Sub ExecuteCode_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    resultBox.Text = RunScript(powerShellCodeBox.Text)
End Sub

Private Function RunScript(ByVal scriptText As String) As String
    Dim MyRunSpace As Runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace()
    MyRunSpace.Open()
    Dim MyPipeline As Pipeline = MyRunSpace.CreatePipeline()
    Dim userName As String = "abc"
    Dim password As String = "123"
    Dim myscript As String = "$username = " & Chr(34) & userName & Chr(34) & Environment.NewLine & _
                 "$password = ConvertTo-SecureString  " & Chr(34) & password & Chr(34) & " -AsPlainText -Force" & Environment.NewLine & _
                 "$cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $userName,$password" & Environment.NewLine & _
                 "connect-nacontroller mydrive -credential $cred" & Environment.NewLine
    MyPipeline.Commands.AddScript(myscript)
    MyPipeline.Commands.Add("Out-String")
    Dim results As Collection(Of PSObject) = MyPipeline.Invoke()
    MyRunSpace.Close()
    Dim MyStringBuilder As New StringBuilder()
    For Each obj As PSObject In results
        MyStringBuilder.AppendLine(obj.ToString())
    Next
    Return MyStringBuilder.ToString()

End Function
```

Comment: post your correction as an answer, and you can accept your own answer after waiting 24 hrs. You'll get 15 rep-points. Good luck and keep posting!

Comment: Thanks for the heads up!  I tried to, but it wouldn't let me b/c it was less than 8 hours from the time I posted it.  But I'll fix it later!

Comment: Ah, so the wait time is 8 hrs, not 24, good to know. I'll revise my 'accept your own answer for rep-points' advice to new users in the future. Thanks and good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right before the username line, I added this line:
"Import-Module DataOnTap" & Environment.NewLine & _**